# Should I use OOP to reduce clutter, or only when I can see myself reusing code?

Tags: php, oop

I've tried to understand OOP for a while now (although haven't had much spare time to do much). While the cars and books analogies helped me understand the concept, I have kept failing trying to find a real world scenario (relating to a PHP program with database access).

Here is my most recent attempt at using OOP. It is a simple program submitting a user message to a database.

```
require_once('init.php');
require_once('Classes.php');

$message = new ContactMessage($db);

if(!$message->validateForm()){

    $message -> returnSessionError('Failed to validate your form. Please try again');
    header('Location: ../index.php?p=contact');

}else if($message->checkSubmissions(3,10) == false){    //form info okay, check if ip has submitted more than the allowed times. Sets max for 5mins and 24hrs respectively.
    if($message->max5mins == true){ //maximum allowed messages in 5min period
        $message ->returnSessionError('Too many messages have been sent from the same IP address. 
                                                    Please wait at least 5 minutes and try again.');
        header('Location: ../index.php?p=contact');                                                         
    }elseif($message->max24hrs == true) {   //max allowed in a day
        $message ->returnSessionError('To prevent spam, your IP address has been blocked for 24 hours. Please try again later.');
        header('Location: ../index.php?p=contact');                 
    }

}else{  //everything is fine, add to database.
    if($message -> insertToDB()){
        $message -> returnSuccess('Thank you for your message, I\'ll get back to you ASAP.');
        header('Location: ../index.php?p=contact');         
    }else{
        $message -> returnSessionError('Something has gone wrong in our server - Please try again later.');
        header('Location: ../index.php?p=contact');                 
    }
}
```

To me, I'm still seeing my code as using a bunch of functions, except now it's wrapped around a `Class`. Is this the correct use of OOP, or am I just pretending to use it?

Thanks

Comment: [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232777/php-vs-oo-php-which-one-to-use)

Comment: This should be moved at codereview.stackexchange.com, but a quick note: you have taken the first step in OO -- encapsulation (as in "bundling data and code together"). However there is still much to do in the `else if` branch; this code should not need to know about `checkSubmissions(3,10)` (what is 3 and 10?) and it should not need to know about `max5mins` or anything like that. `$message` should instead expose a `getValidationErrors` method or something similar.

Comment: @Jon Thank you, that makes a lot of sense! The 3 and 10 were the maximum number of submissions allowed by an IP address, so as to make the code more flexible later on. Would it be better to use another method such as `setMaxSubmissions` instead?

Comment: It also seems like you are violating the [Single responsibility principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). E.g `ContactMessage` does validation and interacts with the DB.

Comment: @tgun926: Yes, or perhaps `minSubmissions` and `maxSubmissions` properties you can set independently.

Comment: @atomman The validation is specific to this particular class though, so I don't think I could use it with anything else. Should I be doing something like `ValidateMessages extends ContactMessage`, or still have a separate class for `ValidateMessages`?

Comment: Obs: it's a good practice put `exit`s after all `header('location:...')`s.

Comment: @tgun926 I see no problem with having the validation within the `ContactMessage`. Interactions with DB should not be there imho, and I would probably perfer a [DAO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object) or [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) approach instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In terms of OOP, you're doing it wrong because you're mixing concepts and responsibilities.
What you're doing here is dealing with data validation, including both input's and record's

The form validator basically consists of two parts:

#### Input validator

It basically checks if values are not empty, their maximal or minimal length.

#### Record Validator

It basically queries a storage to find out about record existence and generates appropriate error message.

#### Form Validator itself

Its a bridge between input and record validators. It basically check if fields are valid, then starts checking for records. If both inputs and records are valid, then its `isValid()` method returns true, otherwise it returns `false` and populates an array with error messages.

```
$dataMapper = new ContactMapper($pdo);

$inputValidator = new InputValidator();
$recordValidator = new RecordValidator($dataMapper);

$formValidator = new FormValidator($inputValidator, $recordValidator);


if ($formValidator->isValid($data)) {
   
    if ($dataMapper->insert($data)){
        // Success, do something like a redirect
    } else {
       // Failed to insert
    }

} else {
    
   print_r($formValidator->getErrors());
}
```

### What would you gain here?

In terms of OOP, you're adhering to the [Single-Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) and [Separation of Concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) at the same time, because you do encapsulate separated responsibility within a class that serves it. Thus you'll be able to modify one part of an application without altering another one.

### Dealing with storage logic - is another responsibility too

And that should be basically encapsulated within a [Mapper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_mapper_pattern) that abstract an access to a table.

Comment: `$data` should be the `$contactMessage` domain model.

Comment: @Tomás There are no models in MVC. A model is an abstraction layer that consist of several classes. `$data` actually should be substituted with input values.

Comment: You say `InputValidator` should be a separate class, but the way it works will be very specific for this program (I can't validate any other form which doesn't have the same format). Therefore, wouldn't `InputValidator` be an extension of the `FormValidator` class, or is there no such rule?

Answer (score 0):

### Assumptions

I suppose this file of yours is, alone, just responsible for the execution of this script. No others scripts, neither HTML codes. Let's call it "post.php".

### Answering the title question

In the OOP paradigm, you **ALWAYS** create your code oriented, not just when you can reuse code.

### Answering the body question

In my opinion, in order for you to have a good OOP implementation, all scripts must be inside classes, except those that call the methods, and whatever else you need and can't put inside the classes (sorry, it's difficult to be more specific in the latter). You have two possibilities:

1. GET pages: get infos from the server and mix with the views (i.e. HTMLs; `main` methods in others languages), creating dinamic pages;
2. POST pages: targets from yours forms; in separated pages without any HTML, post infos to the server, like yours "post.php".

So, your script should be inside some class, it could be the `ContactMessage`, and in the "post.php", you just call the method of `ContactMessage`, something like `postMessage`, that does all this stuff.

Being more clear, i would create a `postMessage` method inside the `ContactMessage` class and call `validateForm`, `checkSubmissions`, `insertToDB`... from other classes (instead of the own `ContactMessage`), to create the "Single Responsibility" like the others said. One class responsible for the validation, one to abstract the DB and so on...

### Final considerations

In my short experience, a real scenario it's a bit more complex than this, but you go adapting along the way corresponding to the needs.

One last thing: i would put all the redirections outside the class, in the "post.php", and would be just two possible redirections, one if fails and one if succeeds.